# set a variable in a function swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]

How can I use the var uniqueNumber in the createLeaderboard function and reuse it again. At the bottom I print unique Number again and it gives me 0 because it's taking the value I had when I first initialized it. When I get the data from firebase it should be set to a number that is not 0. So basically I'm asking how can i set the uniqueNumber variable and use it in the function without it reseting to the default value

Comment: Unrelated to your direct problem, but still really important: It looks to me like your code is in need of a struct for this; `struct LeaderboardEntry`, containing `points: Int`, `name; String` and `fullName: String`. You should try to never right `= ""`, empty strings are almost never a valid default value.

Comment: No pictures of code please.

Comment: please update your question and remove the photo of the code, look up how to properly format code in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable from

```
var uniqueNumber = 0
```

to this

```
var uniqueNumber: Int?
```

NOTE:

In your function call where you change use your uniqueNumber variable,

here: `self.uniqueNumber = documentData["tally"] as! Int`

make sure the 'tally data' actually has a value that is changing your variable.
Simply print the value to double check it is actually modifying your data

Comment: It is running through it, however it dosen’t keep the variable. Can I send you the code to looks at?

Comment: @CaptainDilan sure thing